# Increase the padding from the top to the first Row of a Grid View

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a Gridview.extent within a container and I want to increase the gap from the top of the first element to the top of the Gridview. If I add padding around the Gridview, the entries are cut off while I am scrolling down, so that is not a solution for me.

What I need is a way to increase the padding from the Top to the first Row of the Grid View, but I want the distanced between the entries the same as they are
Code:

```
GridView.extent(
            maxCrossAxisExtent: ((MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2) - (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 10.0)),
            // crossAxisCount: 3,
            mainAxisSpacing: 8,
            //shrinkWrap: true,
            childAspectRatio: getFittingAxisSpacing(),
            children: menuItems,
          ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't the `padding` of the `GridView` what you want?

```
GridView.extent(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
  maxCrossAxisExtent: ((MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2) - (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 10.0)),
  mainAxisSpacing: 8,
  childAspectRatio: getFittingAxisSpacing(),
  children: menuItems,
),
```